# Package Large Electron Application For Multiple OS

Tags: electron

I am new to Electron, but have experience with NW.JS. In NW.JS, I have my project bundled as so:

```
|> Project Root
|-----> Linux NW.JS Directory
|-----> Windows NW.JS Directory
|-----> Application Directory
```

When I start the application, I have a program that detects the OS, then launches as so (psuedo):

```
if(is_running_on_linux){
    exec("project_root/linux_nw_directory/nw", args: "project_root/application");
}else if(is_running_on_windows){
    exec("project_root/windows_nw_directory/nw.exe", args: "project_root/application");
}
```

The application is huge... So I only want to have one application directory. I don't want one for each OS. Logistically it wouldn't make sense.

Is this possible using Electron, if so... what toolchain do I use to build it as so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a report in case anyone is reading this:
I convinced the client to move off of Electron and on to NW.JS so we could package the application properly.